# Securing slate tiles over outdoor cement slab

Tags: tile, adhesive, patio, cement

Here's a cement patio that was covered decades ago with slate tiles.  Some along the edges have popped up.  Underneath the popped tiles we can see that the slab has cracked.

What are proper and/or expedient ways to resecure these tiles to the slab?

[image: Popped slate patio tiles]

Comment: Thinset [under] and grout [in-between]; possibly the same all-in-one product. You should probably watch some video tutorial how to mix and apply these.

Comment: You will also want to scrape up the loose stuff, I would grind the area so when reset the repaired tiles are not higher than the old ones.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason for the tile popping and crack  is water getting under tile and freezing.  First remove old thinset and clean.  I would use a roll on waterproofer like RedGard to seal concrete. Use a polymer-modified adhesive thinset rated for outside use to install slate and grout.